# Issues with softlink

Tags: unix

I am trying to create a softlink through unix command 
that is ln -s /ajay/i4sites/i4gear.com/docs/includes /ajay/i4sites/i4content.com/docs/includes
but this always give one message this is not in directory.
I want to know only one thing that for creating softlink unix command svn should be worked or not.Is it compulsory.i have execute the command svn status svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy.
so please clear me..

Comment: It's hard to figure what you're asking. For one the `ln` command has nothing to do with the `svn` (Subversion) command.

Comment: `ln -s from to`: Are you sure `from` exists?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 common forms in which ln is used.

- `$ ln target link_name` :create link to target with the link name
  “link_name” in current directory.
- `$ ln target` :create link to target with the same link name.
- `$ ln target directory` :create link to target (link name same) in
  the specified directory.

Small tutorial [here](http://www.cs-repository.info/search/label/hard%20links%20soft%20links) on Hard and Soft links.